# ASP.NET Core: how to run npm script command in startup.cs file?

Tags: asp.net-core, npm

Is there any way to run `npm` command which defined in `package.json` file when starting up the program in asp.net core 2.1?

For example:

startup.cs:

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
   ABCMiddleware(npmScript: "build");
 }
```

and package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple way would be

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
  // path may be different on different machines
  string yarnPath = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Yarn\\bin\\yarn.cmd";
  Process.Start(yarnPath, "build");
}
```

For more control the [`ProcessStartInfo` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-6.0) show other ways to run it